Sumif formula containing a certain text
I have a formula
=sumifs(Sheet2!F:F,Sheet2!E:E,"*"&Sheet1!A2&"*",Sheet2!C:C,'Sheet1'!B2)

which does not work. I am trying to perform a sumif formula based on if column A on sheet 1 contains a certain text in sheet 2 column E
]1

=sumifs(Sheet2!F:F,Sheet2!E:E,""&Sheet1!A2&"",Sheet2!C:C,'Sheet1'!B2)

Corrected - However, I am still have issues on returning the data

Works fine for me: https://i.sstatic.net/esP8C.png. Some important detail is missing from your question likely.

Do you get an error?  The wrong result?  What does which does not work mean?
